# How to pass array index in image src in Vuejs v-img?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Hey im trying to iterate through an array of urls to feed it inside of my `src` attribute. I'm not sure about the correct syntax to use. Can you help me?
I have my array called `DataArray` made of images url, and i want to insert inside of `v-img` in `v-row`. i tried this `:src=DataArray[n]` but it's not the correct way.

```html
<template>
  <v-container v-if="Dataloaded" class="dark">
    <v-row no-gutters>
      <template v-for="n in 6">
        <v-col :key="n">
          <v-card dark class="mx-auto" max-width="344">
            <v-img :src=DataArray[n] height="200px"></v-img>

            <v-card-title>Title</v-card-title>

            <v-card-subtitle>Anime-Descriptions</v-card-subtitle>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn text>View</v-btn>

              <v-btn color="purple" text>Explore</v-btn>

              <v-spacer></v-spacer>

              <v-btn icon @click="show = !show">
                <v-icon>{{ show ? 'mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi-chevron-down' }}</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>

            <v-expand-transition>
              <div v-show="show">
                <v-divider></v-divider>

                <v-card-text>I'm a thing. But, like most politicians, he promised more than he could deliver. You won't have time for sleeping, soldier, not with all the bed making you'll be doing. Then we'll go with that data file! Hey, you add a one and two zeros to that or we walk! You're going to do his laundry? I've got to find a way to escape.</v-card-text>
              </div>
            </v-expand-transition>
          </v-card>
          <!-- spacing -->
          <br :key="1" />
          <br :key="2" />
        </v-col>
        <v-responsive v-if="n === 3" :key="`width-${n}`" width="100%"></v-responsive>
      </template>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import db from "@/Firebase/firebaseInit";

export default {
  name: "Grid",
  data() {
    return {
      DataArray: [],
      Dataloaded: false,
      show: false
    };
  },
  created() {
    let ArtData = db.collection("artworks").doc("yWnmwHTxMhvobLi21FNw");
    ArtData.get()
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          // This variable contains all the necessary artworks for display
          let DataArray = doc.data().Array;
          console.log("Document data!:", DataArray);
          this.Dataloaded = true;
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see when logging `DataArray`?

Comment: @Dan i see my array :)

Comment: @Dan i added a pic

Comment: Do you see any images?  The loop counter syntax is a little off but it seems adequate to at least show some images.

Comment: No i dont with [n], i tried to put manually a random url in my array in src to see if it appears and it did.

Comment: i also tried DataArray[1] and nothing show off, but i got no errors

Comment: And you're sure that these URLs are correct?  Should work (but use `n-1` since the `v-for` you're using is 1-based):  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/8kcp9m4s/

Comment: @Dan yes 100% sure, i've though that maybe when i try to access the array..well its still trying to load the urls from the database so src gets an empty array. thats why i added :Dataloaded

Comment: Oh you didn't set `this.DataArray = DataArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```js
let DataArray = doc.data().Array;
```

to:

```js
this.DataArray = doc.data().Array;
```

And use this to show the image:

```html
<v-img :src="DataArray[n-1]" height="50px"></v-img>
```

`n-1` because the `v-for` you're using is 1-based.